# How to pass URI string in nginx url

Tags: nginx

Currently I have an nginx server which is serving as a reverse proxy that is just forwarding all requests to another server; user goes to testurl.test.com and it forwards to another server but keeps the same url, my current conf looks like the below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78;
    }
}
```

What I would like is to have the uri passed through to a different port like this;

User goes to testurl.test.com, it then forwards to testurl.test.com:8080/someurlstringhere

Everything after the / is somewhat dynamic (although I have a list of about 9 different parameters that may be used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-- EDIT --

My current implementation is this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  11.22.33.444;

    location / {
        return 301 http://12.34.56.78:8080/urlstringhere;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, `nginx` will pass the `uri` requested to the `proxy server` by default. [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you missed some important details, but if it really that simple, then you can use return

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

        location / {
          return 301 http://testurl.test.com:8080/someurlstringhere
           }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the rewriting of the original url to http://testurl.test.com:8080 works, but adding anything after / doesn't seem to get passed through.  Any ideas?

Comment: @MitchDavis, please share your current implementation

Comment: I've updated my question with my current implementation

Comment: Can you show me output of "curl -v testurl.test.com" ?